# Define style in ng-grid cellTemplate

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an ng-grid with below code:

```
$scope.gridOptionsReports = {
    data: 'Reports',
    multiSelect: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Row', displayName: 'Row', width: 40 },
        { field: 'OperationStatus', displayName: 'Operations ', width: 200 },
        { field: 'Date', displayName: ' Date', cellTemplate: '<input class="fieldtext" type="text" ng-click="reportExistChecker(currentDocumentIndex)" ui-mask="9999/99/99" style="width: 80px; margin-right: 10px; text-align:center;">', width: 100 },
        { field: 'Consideration', displayName: 'Consideration', cellTemplate: '<label>Exist</label><input type="checkbox" ng-click="reportExistChecker(row)">', width: 200 }
    ]
};
```

1. How i can change style in my cells? (My style isn't working)
2. I want to write two html code inside my cellTemplate together. (Like my last row of ng-grid. (My code isn't working.)

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? And you have a typo here `margin-righ`should be `margin-right`

Comment: Thanks for it. It is my type mistake. But i meant any style like width and text-align and so on, not working.Also my ui-mask is not working too.